# Jenkins EnvInject build step

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have a Jenkins job that is doing the following (amongst other things):

1. Read user input for ENVIRONMENT and SERVERTYPE
2. Inject environment variable AGENT (initially blank) as a build step to create
   a new variable
3. Execute shell as a build step to populate AGENT, based on what was entered
   in ENVIRONMENT and SERVERTYPE
4. Use AGENT as an input to a plugin as a post build action

The problem is that the value of AGENT doesn't seem to persist outside of the "execute shell" build step.  When I try and pass it into the post build action plugin, it's still blank.

Can anyone point out what am I doing wrong?  I have read the documentation, but can't seem to figure it out.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is that whatever variables you set in the shell script, they don't make it out.
This is true for any process: child process (your shell script) can never directly affect environment of parent process (Jenkins executor client).

If you need the data to persist, you need to store it outside the script; there are many options like uploading it to a server or storing it in a database, the most obvious and easiest option is to save it to a file.

You can even save the value to a "properties file" in the syntax supported by EnvInject and specify path in "Properties File Path" field.

Answer (score 0):

You need to populate properties file with the values of the environment variables to be injected again, so they will survive until post-build actions. The properties file usually resides in the job's workspace.

For example use the following steps:

1. Build step "Execute shell" :

`AGENT="My agent"
echo AGENT=$AGENT > my.properties`

2. Build step: "Inject environment variables",
   Field "Properties File Path": 
   `$WORKSPACE/my.properties`
3. Post-Build Actions: "Editable Email Notification", Field "Default Content":

`Current Agent $AGENT
Or ${ENV, var="AGENT"}`